# how to pass the error messages from back end(sails.js) to front end

Tags: node.js, sails.js

If i have to pass any message/error to front end , in sails.js.

Either we can use one of the following below.

```
  1. res.view({error : error}) 
  2. res.view("/otherpageurl", {error : error})
  3. res.redirect("/otherpageurl?error="+error)
```

In some cases , If iam in page A , if any error occurs , i just want to redirect to another page with the error message passed to frontend.whereas in some cases , i just want to show the error in same page.

Is there any other possiblity of passing error messages to frontend?

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Technically* you can use the flash middleware for this...

So you would do it like:

```
req.flash('error', 'Error Message!')
res.redirect('/otherpageurl');
```

Then on your view:

```
<%- req.flash('error') %>
```

Comment: Why "technically"?  This is a fine answer, no need to qualify it :)  One note: `req.flash('error')` will clear the error out, so you can only call it once.  If you want to check for the error's existence first, you can examine `req.session.flash.error`.  If you're serving the view from a controller with `res.view`, a good practice is to merge the flash vars into the locals, e.g. `req.view('myView', {locals: {flash: req.flash()}})`, giving your view a `flash` object that you can work with without worrying about things disappearing.