# Changing view from a controller in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I simply want to print a sentence in part of a view file . But the controller decides for it.
Here is my controller file **loginController**

```
login: function(req, res){
  var x = new LdapService();

  console.log('inside log in action') ;
  x.loginSuccessful(req.body.userid, req.body.password, function(isAuth){
      console.log(isAuth) ;
      if(isAuth )
          res.send('successful login');
      else
          res.render('login/index', document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Log in failde. Please check your Username or Password");
  });
},
```

I dont want to use jSon. I just want a javascript command is executed and prints a scentence in my view. But controller and login function should decide about it.

My **view file**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>    
    <br>
    <p id="message"></p>
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that you've [read the documentation for views](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Views) or [view locals](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Views/Locals.html).  It also looks like you're confusing back-end code (your Sails controller) with front-end code; things like `document.getElementById` are for manipulating the DOM on the front-end, after the browser has already rendered it.

What you want in your action instead of `res.render` is:

```
res.view('login/index', 
    {message: "Log in failed. Please check your Username or Password"}
);
```

and in your view:

```
<p id="message"><%=message%></p>
```

Note that EJS will throw an error if it encounters any unbound variables in a template, so every time you render the login view with `res.view` you'll have to set the `message` local, even if it's to an empty string.

You may also want to consider using [flash messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234457/how-to-pass-the-error-messages-from-back-endsails-js-to-front-end/23235035#23235035) for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend.as you said it throws an error. <%=message%> is undefined. How can I define it in a my HTML page and initialize it with empty ?

Comment: You could do `<%= message = '' || message %>`